# Como usar unload com angular JS?

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, async

O unload deveria ser chamado ao sair da página e bater uma url qualquer de outro site.

Numa versão antiga, sem Angular JS, fazendo isso, funciona normal, ele chama a requisição, quando ligo o debug a API está entrando...

```
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault = true;
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                if (shouldAsk)
                    e.returnValue = 'Se você sair agora desta atividade, irá perder automaticamente uma tentativa!!';
            };

            var didSelectReturn = false;
            $(window).unload(function(){
                if (!didSelectReturn && shouldAsk) {
                    giveup(function(){

                    }, false);
                }
            });

    function giveup(callback, async)
            {
                async = typeof async !== 'undefined' ? async : true;
                if(_started!=null)
                {

                    window.clearInterval(myTimer);
                    var seconds = secondsCount;

                    _started = null;

                    sendDataWithAction_type(LoggeUserID,"quiz", json.id, "time", "giveup", "0", "0", seconds, function(){ // success

                        callback();
                    }, function(){ // error
                        //NSLog(@"sendDataWithAction_type error");
                        callback();
                    }, async);
                    //--
                }
                else{
                    callback();
                } 

function sendDataWithAction_type(user_id, action_type, action_id, data_type, value, start, end, seconds_time, success, error, async) {

    async = typeof async !== 'undefined' ? async : true;
    var GETparams = "user_id="+user_id;
    GETparams += "&action_type="+action_type;
    GETparams += "&action_id="+action_id;
    GETparams += "&data_type="+data_type;
    GETparams += "&value="+value;
    GETparams += "&start="+start;
    GETparams += "&end="+end;
    GETparams += "&seconds="+seconds_time;
    var checkToken = readCookie("gutentoken");
    var checkEmail = readCookie("gutenemail");
    var params = "gutentoken="+checkToken+"&gutenemail="+checkEmail;
   var url = "/"+FOLDER_ADM+"/add-bigdata.php?"+GETparams;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,

        type: "POST",
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        async:async,
        timeout:60000,
        success: function(data) {
            // if (data.status=="200") {
            //     clearInterval(intervalTime);
            // } else {
            //     clearInterval(intervalTime);
            // }
            seconds = 0;

        },
        error: function(data) {

            if(typeof window.parent.data_form !== 'undefined'){
                if(data.status != 404 && window.parent.data_form.withOutInternet == false){
                    window.parent.data_form.withOutInternet = true;
                }
            }
            alert("Erro ao enviar informações, você pode estar sem internet, tente novamente.");
        }
    });

}
```

Agora, quando coloco AngularJS, a requisição async = false não está entrando quando saio do sistema e acesso um endereço do google por exemplo, a API não é chamada. O que estou fazendo errado?

```
$scope.init = function() {

 window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

                        if(!$scope.btnReturn){

                            e = e || window.event;
                            e.preventDefault = true;
                            e.cancelBubble = true;
                            e.returnValue = 'Se você sair agora desta atividade, irá perder automaticamente uma tentativa!!';
                        }
                    };

                    window.addEventListener('unload', function() {

                          var data = {
                              activity_id: atividade,
                              timeoff: $scope.timeOff.tempo_total,
                              date_steps: $scope.dateSteps
                          };

                        var url = "api-games/give-up";

                        var dados = {
                            csrf_token: csrf,
                            user_id: data_form.user_id,
                            activity_id: data.activity_id,
                            timeoff: data.timeoff,
                            date_steps: data.date_steps

                        };


                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data:dados,
                            async: false,
                            timeout:60000,
                            url: url + '/?rand=' + randUrl()
                        });

                    });

 };


 $scope.init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido usando o javascript puro da seguinte forma:

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

                        if(!$scope.btnReturn){

                            e = e || window.event;
                            e.preventDefault = true;
                            e.cancelBubble = true;
                            e.returnValue = 'Se você sair agora desta atividade, irá perder automaticamente uma tentativa!!';
                        }
                    };

                    if (!$scope.final_game && $scope.started_game) {
                        window.addEventListener('unload', sendData, false);
                    }

                    function sendData() {

                        if(!$scope.btnReturn) {
                            var url = "api-games/give-up";

                            var data = {
                                activity_id: atividade,
                                timeoff: $scope.timeOff.tempo_total,
                                date_steps: $scope.dateSteps
                            };

                            var dados = {
                                token: getTokenGames(url),
                                csrf_token: csrf,
                                user_id: data_form.user_id,
                                activity_id: data.activity_id,
                                timeoff: data.timeoff,
                                date_steps: data.date_steps

                            };

                            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            client.open("POST", url, false); 
                            client.send(JSON.stringify(dados));
                        }
                    }
```